# Sparse matrix vector product using PETSC

Tags: sparse-matrix, petsc, matrix, vector

I am trying to do a simple parallel sparse matrix vector multiplications using PETSC. My sparse matrix is a simple tridiagonal laplacian matrix, which is distributed over multiple processors using PETSC.

My main question is that if I do the same operation by simply iterating over the vector and updating each value
A[i] = -1*A[i-1] + 2*A[i] + -1*A[i+1], 
 it takes much lesser time than by using the PETSC SpMV. Why is it so? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: One note that may or may not be relevant: unless you're doing a Gauss-Seidel solve of a tridiagonal system, you likely have a bug in your hard-coded method. As written, you're updating A[i] in one loop iteration and using it again in the next, which is different than computing the matrix-vector product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I assume that you are comparing multiplication with an *assembled* PETSc matrix with your hand-coded *matrix-free* method. The latter may indeed be faster, but this could be because no entries of `A` need be loaded from memory. A more meaningful comparison might be to a matrix-free operator in PETSc (see Section 3.3 in the manual).
- Once you have an apples-to-apples comparison, you can try to determine if any remaining speed differences are due to PETSc overhead or not by using an optimized build (`configure --with-debugging=0`) and running your code with the `-log_summary` option to see timings of various operations.

Comment: @ShivamMalhotra, it would be good if you could say what part of this answer led to the solution and what the ultimate performance improvement was.

Comment: @BillBarth : Loading repeated entries of A again and again from memory were one of the reasons of the bad performance

Comment: Should be `configure --enable-debug=0`, no?

Comment: No (this is PETSc's `configure`, not autotools if that's where you are getting that flag).